# Android stopping the previous mediaplayer?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, togglebutton

I have 3 toggle buttons. I had it working that when clicked it would play a sound and the button would toggle to "stop". when the sound is finished it would toggle back to "play" If you click "stop" while it is playing the sound will stop and toggle back.

However my problem is that if I click two buttons and they both were playing I could not stop the previous one. This is because I could not access the previous mediaPlayer only the current. Here is my current attempt, any help would be great, thanks!

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
    {

    int  soundFile = 0;

    switch (v.getId()) 
    {

    case (R.id.btnSound1):

        soundFile = R.raw.sound1;

    break;
        case (R.id.btnSound2):

        soundFile = R.raw.sound2;

    break;
    case (R.id.btnSound3):

        soundFile = R.raw.sound3;

    break;

   }

    final ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(v.getId()); //gets current button
    MediaPlayer media = (MediaPlayer) button.getTag();                  //gets mediaPlayer object stored in button
    if(button.getTag().equals(null))                          //only runs this once, if the mediaPlayer stored object is null (doesn't exist)
    {
      media = getMedia(soundFile);
      button.setTag(media);            //set the new media object to the buttons tag
      media.start();


     media.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)     //when sound is over
        {
            button.setChecked(true); //set back to play
            mp.release();
        }
    });

    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){           //when clicked
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) 
        {

            if(button.isChecked())      // if stop toggle clicked
            {
                button.setChecked(true); // set to play
                MediaPlayer media = (MediaPlayer) button.getTag();
                media.release();    //stop the sound
            }

            else if(!button.isChecked()) //if play toggle clicked
            {
                 MediaPlayer media = (MediaPlayer) button.getTag();
             media.start(); //play the sound
             button.setChecked(false); //set to stop

            }

        }
       });

    }


}   

public MediaPlayer getMedia(int sound)
{

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(100,100);  //sets the volume to max

    return mediaPlayer;
}
```

Comment: You could keep a reference to the current MediaPlayer object as a private field of the class; that way you can call stop() on it before replacing it with the new one. Or event better, reuse the MediaPlayer object.

Comment: I have it working now so when you click a new button the previous stops but the button does not change back to play. How can I add something like a onMediaStop listener to the button? it already changes back when the media is complete just not if stopped

Comment: You shouldn't need a listener, just keep a reference to the button that launched the MediaPlayer and change it back when you stop the audio.